# getting size of file from MD5 hash

Tags: md5, sha256

I have the md5 and sha256 hash of a file, I would like to calculate the size of the file from the hash value.

Is there any way to get the size of a file with md5 or sha256 hash  of that file available with us ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the size of a file with md5 or sha256 hash of that file available with us ?

No, there is no way to determine the size of a file using its hash. That is based on the nature of a `hash`: same output size for every input size.

32 characters / 128 bits for `md5` and 64 characters / 256 bits for `sha256`